# Trouble dealing with setState async function equivalent with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

```
import React from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./../contexts";
import {
  removeStoredAuthData,
  storedAuthIsValid,
  storeNewAuthData,
} from "./../utils/auth";
import { getUserInfos } from "./../api/userAuthentication";

class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          user: this.state.user,
          clearUserProfile: () => {
            const user = "";
            removeStoredAuthData();
            this.setState({ user });
          },
          saveUserProfile: (response) => {
            const user = response.data;
            storeNewAuthData(response);
            this.setState({ user });
          },
          populateUserProfile: (displayLoader, hideLoader) => {
            const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("appsante-token");
            const storedId = localStorage.getItem("appsante-id");
            if (storedAuthIsValid()) {
              displayLoader(() => {
                getUserInfos(storedId)
                  .then((response) => {
                    const user = { ...response.data, token: storedToken };
                    this.setState({ user }, hideLoader());
                  })
                  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
              });
            }
          },
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default UserProvider;
```

Hi everyone !

I trying to convert a React class component into a function component, with hooks.

But I can't find a way to deal properly with that line :

```
this.setState({ user }, hideLoader());
```

Unlike setState in class components, useState doesn't take a callback as second parameter, and I can't find how to achieve it with useEffect.

Could anyone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: `this.setState({ user }, hideLoader());` That shouldn't work unless it's a HOF. Do you mean `this.setState({ user }, hideLoader);`?

Answer (score 0):

Because the loader's presence can't be determined from the value in / change in `user` alone, you'll need another state variable, maybe one that contains the callback - perhaps call it `hideLoader`. After `getUserInfos` resolves, call `setHideLoader` with the callback, so that a `useEffect` hook with that function as a dependency can see the change and call the callback:

```
const [hideLoader, setHideLoader] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  if (hideLoader) {
    hideLoader(); // or, if this is a HOF: hideLoader()()
    setHideLoader(); // callback done; remove callback from state
  }
}, [hideLoader]);
// ...
  populateUserProfile: (displayLoader, hideLoaderParam) => {
    // ...
    getUserInfos(storedId)
      .then((response) => {
        setUser({ ...response.data, token: storedToken }); // hook version
        setHideLoader(hideLoaderParam);
      })
```

and the rest of your code can be mostly the same - only call `setHideLoader` up above, inside `getUserInfos`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this :-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    
populateUserProfile: async (displayLoader, hideLoader) => {
                const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("appsante-token");
                const storedId = localStorage.getItem("appsante-id");
                if (storedAuthIsValid()) {
                  displayLoader();
                    let  response = await getUserInfos(storedId)
                    const user = { ...response.data, token: storedToken };
                    setUser(user);
                    hideLoader();
                  };
                }
```